# Is it possible to use a flutter plugin's platform code from my app's platform code?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I've been working with Flutter for more than a year now and that's how I got started to Android development.

As the need for android services and other things came to our requirements, I began immersing myself to more and more Java Android, which I'm not really that used to working with admittedly.

So the question really is, can I use a flutter plugin's Java code and use the exposed methods?

I'm specifically interested in `flutter_secure_storage`'s functions so that I could use them outside of Dart.

I know I could just copy the code over, but if there's a better way to reference the project over, I don't have to have the same code on 2 different places.

Additional Info: I initially felt that I can just use the following code:

```
final HashMap<String, String> args = new HashMap<>();
args.put("key", "some-key");
args.put("value", "some-value");
final MethodCall mc = new MethodCall("put", args);
new FlutterSecureStoragePlugin().onMethodCall(mc, new MethodChannel.Result() {
   @Override
   public void success(@Nullable Object result) {
       // do something
   }

   // other overrides
        
});
```

But the plugins require an instance of a `BinaryMessenger` to initialize the `MethodChannel` - at the very least, what I think I can do is to create an instance of the `FlutterEngine` to initialize the plugin first before calling `onMethodCall`.